# dotnet v7 native aot publish gives error message "clang error linker command failed with exit code 1" cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: .net, native, publish, libstdc++, aot

I want to compile my c#/f# project with new native aot (which comes with dotnet v7) on my linux machine.

My csproj/fsproj file has these lines:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I try to compile with `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release` I get the output below:

```bash
...
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/userhome/MyProject/MyProject.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.201/Sdks/Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler/build/Microsoft.NETCore.Native.targets(346,5): error MSB3073: The command ""clang" "obj/Release/net7.0/linux-x64/native/FileServer.o" -o "bin/Release/net7.0/linux-x64/native/FileServer" /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/sdk/libbootstrapper.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/sdk/libRuntime.ServerGC.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/framework/libSystem.Native.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/framework/libSystem.Globalization.Native.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/framework/libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/framework/libSystem.Net.Security.Native.a /userhome/.nuget/packages/runtime.linux-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler/7.0.3/framework/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.a -g -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--as-needed -pthread -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lz -lrt -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--discard-all -Wl,--gc-sections" exited with code 1. [/userhome/MyProject/MyProject.csproj]
```

How can i solve this error and compile my dotnet project as native aot?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is absence of `libstdc++`, or some missing symbolic links that directs to it.

At `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/{versionNum}` folder, there should be a symbolic link  named `libstdc++.so`.

In my environment there are 2 versions, **11** and **12**, at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

I runned `apt list --installed libstdc++*` to see installed versions. There were `libstdc++-11-dev`, but nothing about **12**. So I installed `libstdc++-12-dev` and the problem is solved.